# NServiceBus: Testing that event is published AND exception is thrown at the same time

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nservicebus

I ran across some code in one of our services that looks like this:

```
try
{
    // Step 1: collect underpants.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // If this is the last retry we'll raise an event.
    if (Bus.IsLastRetry())
    {
        PublishFailedEvent(ex);
    }

    // But we'll also send the error to the error queue no matter what.
    throw;
}
```

And a test that looks like this:

```
Test.Handler(bus => new Processor() { Bus = bus })
    .ExpectPublish<IFailedEvent>()
    .OnMessage<ISomeHappenedEvent>();
```

Because we are throwing right after publishing the test fails. Is there a way to test that the FailedEvent is published AND the exception is thrown?

Comment: use Thread.Sleep for some time

Comment: @viveknuna that is not a useful suggestion in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the call to Test() in a try catch and then assert against the exception. Depending on the version of NSB, the handler may raise a TargetInvocationException, which you'll need to interrogate to get to the inner exception.

```
try
{
    Test.Handler(bus => new Processor() { Bus = bus }).OnMessage<ISomeHappenedEvent>();
}
catch (MyExpectedException ex)
{
    // Asserts 
    ...
}
```

or,

```
try
{
    Test.Handler(bus => new Processor() { Bus = bus }).OnMessage<ISomeHappenedEvent>();
}
catch (TargetInvocationException ex)
{
    // Asserts against ex.InnerException
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use [NUnit TestFramework](http://www.nunit.org/) you can also use attributes to test expected exception

```
[Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(MyException))]
    public void it_should_throw_attribute()
    {
        Assert.Fail();
    }
```

or if you prefer to use [fluent assertions](http://www.fluentassertions.com/) you can also use this and check for exactly type of thrown exception or just the base exception and do further checking, for excample conaining InnerException, Message, ...

```
[Test]
    public void it_should_throw_exactly()
    {
        Action actionToTest = () => { throw new MyException(); };
        actionToTest.ShouldThrowExactly<MyException>();
    }

    [Test]
    public void it_should_throw()
    {
        Action actionToTest = () => { throw new MyException(); };
        actionToTest.ShouldThrow<Exception>();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If the handler throws an exception then the expectations will not be checked. To test this you could introduce a boolean flag to the handler and split the test into two tests. i.e.

```
[Test]
public void it_should_publish_event()
{
    Test.Handler(bus => new Processor() { Bus = bus, DoNotThrow = true })
        .ExpectPublish<IFailedEvent>()
        .OnMessage<ISomeHappenedEvent>();
}

[Test, ExpectedException(typeof(YourException))]
public void it_should_throw()
{
    Test.Handler(bus => new Processor() { Bus = bus })
        .OnMessage<ISomeHappenedEvent>();
}
```

Be aware that if the transport is configured using the DTC or Outbox then this event won't get published if an exception is thrown in the handler (unless the publish is configured with immediate dispatch).